# Counting the number of men and women from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I want to count the number of male and female riders (which are coded as 1 or 2) in a CSV file, but my code does not seem to be working. This is my code:

```
Men = 0
Women = 0
import csv
with open('dec2week.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            print(row['gender'])
        if 'gender' == 1:
            'gender'Men += 1
        esle:
            'gender'Women += 1

print "Count for Men: ", Men
print "Count for women: ", Women
```

Comment: What is your code doing or not doing that is unexpected? In other words, what does "not working" mean?

Comment: Why did you ever think if *might* work? `'gender' == 1` will **never** be true, `'gender'Men += 1` makes no sense whatsoever and `else` is spelled wrong.

Comment: try using pandas library - it's been built for things like this!

Comment: Did the answers help you? If one of them solved your problem, you can let the community know by marking it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry I haven't checked this in a while, the first answer the Padraic Cunningham posted worked!

Answer (score 2):

Use a Counter dict to do the counting:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
with open('dec2week.csv') as csvfile:
    next(csvfile)
    counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(csv.reader(csvfile)))
```

Then just get the count using the key:

```
print("Total male = {}".format(counts["1"]))
print("Total female = {}".format(counts["2"]))
```

To use a particular column either index each row or use your DictReader approach:

```
 counts = Counter(row["gender"] for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile))
```

Using your for loop you need to access by key and compare the values returned to "1":

```
with open('dec2week.csv') as csvfile:
    m,f = 0,0
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        if row["gender"] == "1":
            m += 1
        else:
            f += 1


print("Total male = {}".format(m))
print("Total female = {}".format(f))
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful advice! Sorry I know this must be an easy question for you, but I am a newbie.

Comment: No worries, the only mistake you made was forgetting to access by key, if you know the gender is the ith column you can also use `csv.reader`  `if row[ith] == "1":...`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `gender` value is located at `row['gender']`, in which case you are almost there, you just need to compare *this value* in your `if` statement and fix a couple of other minor syntax issues:

```
for row in reader:
  # Note you need this indented under your for loop to access each "gender" value in each row
  if row['gender'] == 1:
    Men += 1
  else:  # could also use "elif row['gender'] == 2:" and catch any unexpected values with "else"
    Women += 1
```

If that doesn't work, please post an example of your CSV data so that I can test it and figure out something that will work.

Comment: +1 for showing OP what's needed to move his code from not-working to working. Other answer (so far) is more sophisticated but is probably not what the OP needs at this point in his coding journey.